# Inject javascript file using inspectedWindow.reload

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if it is possible in anyway to inject a javascript file instead of just code statements.

for example (what works):

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload({
  ignoreCache: true,
  injectedScript: 'console.log("Hello World!")'
});
```

but I want to see if I can inject a .js file (doesn't work):

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload({
  ignoreCache: true,
  injectedScript: 'file.js'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this API doesn't allow it, but it's not hard to write a wrapper that does:

1. Request `file.js` using XHR.
2. Call `reload` with the response as `injectedScript`.

For example:

```
function reloadWithFile(scriptFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload({
      ignoreCache: true,
      injectedScript: xhr.responseText
    });
  });
  xhr.open("GET", chrome.runtime.getURL(scriptFile));
  xhr.send();
}
```

Injecting multiple files by concatenating them is left as an exercise ([Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) may be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not or not yet possible to do. But there are other workarounds like inject the file using the `content.js` or using the `background.js` chrome.tabs.executeScript(). You might want to check [using a content script js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) and [background.js](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399)

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is with what `reload()` does. It effectively does a one-time injection of a `run_at: "document_start"` content script. This is going to be very tricky to implement due to timing involved - you can't `executeScript` on the "new" page until navigation is committed, and my that time it may be too late to inject before the page's own scripts.

Comment: Thank for pointing out some info that I missed, up voting your answer